# I18next load resources from different sources

Tags: javascript, ajax, i18next

I want to load resources for some locales from the local context (precompiled js  data on the page) and rest of resources load from the rest service. I18next allows  to provide resources at init time and also it has 'backend' plugin to load resources from the fs or XHR. Both methods work fine but they are not working together. If  I  provide resources for one locale at init time then backend plugin doesn't load resources at all. How can I provide translation for one language at init time and load others on demand? This should be quite a common problem as I just want to have at least fallback locale available at first rendering to avoid showing keys to the user. My translations are stored in the DB so loading fallback locale other ajax is not acceptable as it could take a while to load and also I don't want to preload all the locales as it could be many of them.

Comment: When the i18next is being init, did you add `debug=true` to see what happen is your locale file, was it loaded or not?

Comment: I did. When I provide resources a in init  then it loaded,  but as per description then plugin doesn't work. It is not loading anything.

Comment: could you please give the debug messages, the init code and the resource files name? I wrote an example for the browser usage, https://github.com/iownthegame/i18next_test don't know if it helps

Comment: Does `addResourses()` work for you? http://i18next.com/docs/api/#add-resources. As I understoond you were asking to load some resources file at init , and later you will get some key/values from your db, and want to load together with existing resources?

Comment: @iownthegame  I haven't tried addResources as it is a bit different to what I want to do. AddResources allow adding additional messages to the existing bundle.

Comment: For now, as a workaround, I modified backend plugin to allow load resources from the server and from embedded script. It works okayish, the only downside, the handling code for backend plugin using debounce which results in 250ms delay for any load including from the embedded script.

Comment: @iownthegame thanks for pointing on the feature request.